# Does Scala have modulo in the standard library?

Tags: scala

I'm assuming the answer is no because I can't find it, but it wouldn't be the first time I'd be wrong about that. Meanwhile I usually define it like this:

```
implicit class IntWithMod(x: Int) {
  def mod(y: Int) = x%y+(if (x < 0) y else 0)
}
```

Is there a scala library (ideally the standard library, external works too though if it's not huge) that defines this? If not, is there some easy way to add this to all integral types (doing this manually for each one is kinda tedious).

Answer (score 3):

`%` *is* modulo.  Scala does not have the zero-or-positive version that you wrote above.

You could write the code generically using `scala.math.Integral`, but it would be so slow that you wouldn't want to use it.

Just write it all out.  It should take you only slightly longer than it did to ask this question.

Comment: No its not. `%` is the remainder operation, which may be similar to modulo but isn't the same thing.

Comment: @Cubic - Evidence?  In favor of `%` being modulo: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: (mod n) is an equivalence relation on integers. The modulus operation is supposed to pick _one_ representative per equivalence class. One of the properties of modulus is that (Z mod n;+(mod n)) forms a group, which, amongst other things, means that x+1=y+1 => x=y. (-1)+1 (mod n) = (n-1)+1(mod n) = 0, i.o.w. -1 = n-1 (mod n). If % was the modulus operation it should pick the same representative if two numbers are equal mod n, but it doesn't.

Comment: @Cubic - I agree it's a poor choice mathematically.  I wish programming language designers would not use the same term to mean something that isn't quite what the mathematical term is (vector is particularly painful).  But this is a valid modulo in computer science, so if you want to communicate clearly you can specify that you want a modulo operation that forms a group.  Anyway, the answer is the same regardless of what you call it: no, it's not there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Java standard library modulus function:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorMod-int-int-

```
scala> java.lang.Math.floorMod(-7, 4)
res4: Int = 1

scala> java.lang.Math.floorMod(7, -4)
res5: Int = -1
```